# Load data from file after function finish python

Tags: python

To elaborate:
I have 6 modules/functions in separate files which I try to run from `main.py`.
After running the first script, data is written to `var data`, which inserts that data to `data.py` < confirmed that the data is written.

After that, I run the next function `function2()` which then retrieves that data from `data.py` by import. The issue here is that it seems that function2 is preloaded, so that the data variable is empty.

How can I solve this issue? There are 6 functions using the same data, and I **want** to pull that from .py file, not store it in the cache.

Over 3 hours of trying, and I could not figure it out nor find a similar question. The data in the first function is written to the file perfectly. If I run the scripts apart, they all DO get the data correctly.

Example:
main.py

```
from functions import function1, function2
function1()
print("function 1 done")
function2()
```

function1.py

```
def function1():
    data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    f = open("/data/data.py", "w+")
    f.write("data ="+str(data))
    print(len(data))
    f.close()
    print(len(data)) -> output = 5
```

function2.py

```
from data.data import *
def function2():
    print(len(data))
```

output = 0

So the issue is: The data for function2 is loaded from data.py BEFORE function1 wrote data to data.py.

Comment: Put the `from data.data import *` inside `function2`.

Comment: I tried this, `import *` is not allowed but `import data` still returned `0`

Comment: can you post the code related to data.data?

Comment: When you `import functions` all of the code in `functions.py` is going to be run at that time. So your `from data.data import *` will be executed on the first line of `main.py`. You can't introduce changes to that underlying `data.py` file after it's been imported. As @rdas suggests, move your import into `function2()` will keep that line from executing until `function2()` is executed and this should work (although it feels sketchy and maybe would be a good usecase for `pickle` instead of tiptoeing around code at time of execution).

Comment: @JNevill I think I need to elaborate it a bit more, each function is in a different file, so for example I have the `function getdata`, which is in getdata.py, on top of the getdata.py it has from data.data import ids, so it is not called in the `main.py `. I import the function as from functions import function1,function2 and not use the * to eliminate this boundary, but it seems like it is still loaded on main.py load. I have done what @rdas said, and my return for data is still empty.

Comment: @Kungfupanda data.data is just: data = [1,2,3,4,5] in which the numbers == ids with data